# Pytorch Video model frame_length X sample rate

Tags: video, pytorch, video-processing

Pre-trained pytorch video models have names like:

```
slowfast_4x16_resnet50_kinetics400
```

4 is the frame_length, 16 is the sample rate.

What do they mean. Let us say I have a video at 30 frames per second. Do I take every 16th frame (sample rate) and include 4 such samples as input to the model?

Just trying to figure out what frame length and sample rate mean and how they are used.

Thank you very much

Look at pytorch model documents. No luck so far.